# Android Firebase and AdMob plugin not found

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, admob

So im following this tutorial... https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start?hl=en-US

Im trying to get AdMob on my Android app but when i get to the section where i am adding the plugin to my project i get this error message:

```
Error:(9, 0) Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Dean\AndroidStudioProjects\datrxsync\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

Im adding it to the app level build.gradle. Below is the build.grade file.
Can anyone see what the problem could be??

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.muggysoft.datrxsync"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

you first need to  Add Firebase to Your Android Project

follow [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) guide and hopefully your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this dependency in your root-level (project) build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```